# Make list item "editable"

Tags: sharepoint-designer, external-content-type

I have created a sharepoint list from an external content type (using Sharepoint Designer) with columns Id, Name etc. The fields in the Id column are links and contain a dropdown menu (view, edit, delete item), the other columns don´t. How do I set/remove this column behaviour?

Comment: Does this look like it's what you're trying to do?<br>
<http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/16766/display-the-sharepoint-context-menu-in-list-items-on-another-column-instead-of-t>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In BCS the columns representing your Keys have this behaviour by the default.