# How to add the document context menu to any column other than Name in a documet library?

Tags: document-library, column, ecb-menu

I've tried [this other solution](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/16766/display-the-sharepoint-context-menu-in-list-items-on-another-column-instead-of-t) for lists, and it also works for document libraries but it doesn't add the menu that I need.

This is the menu that gets added:

[image]

And this is the one I need to add:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rather than using `ListItemMenu` and `ListItemMenuAllowed`, try `CalloutMenu` and `CalloutMenuAllowed`.